# How to use cookies for GWT Interface changes

Tags: gwt

how to store gwt user interface settings in persistent cookies, so that user can get them on next visit? I have user interface designed using gwt. Some user prefer to see few columns from the interface every time they visit application.so what needs to be done

Comment: You'd use the static methods in [com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Cookies.html) to set and retrieve cookies. Specifically the `setCookie()` and `getCookie()` methods.

Comment: do i need to provide on setcookie() getcookie method(()? settings for column can be stored in set cookies method? how to test it?

Comment: GWT Cookies only lets you set key/value pairs, as Strings. Kind of like how you would store data in a Java properties file. Please see the link on my previous comment for usage details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage for that.

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html

HTML5 Storage is technology for caching data on client-side. There are two types: LocalStorage (shared by all browser tabs, stored on disk, 5 MB per webapp) and SessionStorage (accessible only within one tab, stored in memory). In your case, you should use LocalStorage to allow user close his browser and then reload settings from disk.

GWT has built-in API for using LocalStorage. See details at http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/storage/client/Storage.html

Also let me propose you some sample code (you'll need to provide some details to be more concrete):

```
      import com.google.gwt.storage.client.Storage;
          ...

          Storage storage = Storage.getLocalStorageIfSupported();
          if (storage != null) {

          //adding your settings to storage
          storage.setItem("some setting key", "some setting");

          //removing your settings from storage
          storage.removeItem("some setting key to remove");

          //clearing the whole storage contents
          storage.clear();

          }
```

Comment: I have edited my original answer. Is it comprehensive enough?